# What lens hood will fit Canon 80-200 f/4.5-5.6 (original)?

Tags: lens, canon, lens-hood

My in-law wants a lens hood for his Canon 80-200 f/4.5-5.6. This is the old version of this lens he inherited from someone, not the "II" version or USM version.

I think the lens hood that will fit is the Canon ET-62 (or some third party knockoff of that hood).  Is that right?

I also see that it looks like Canon has two versions of this hood the ET-62 and ET-62 II. Is there any difference between these?  Do they fit the same lenses?

Update- So I went ahead and got the Canon ET-62 which uses little recessed clips to attach to the lens but it does not fit.  It is about the right size (diameter) but it seems like this lens does not have a mount for a lens hood.  That might explain why I only found one reference to claimed compatibility (and it was wrong).  I guess this is such an budget lens that Canon did not think anyone would want a hood for it.

Answer (score 4):

This question is five years old but I do have the correct answer.

The original Canon EF 80-200mm f/4.5-5.6 did not have a provision to mount a lens hood so there is no designated lens hood for it.

One solution is to use a generic 52mm screw in lens hood.

[image]

A better solution is to use the Canon 62-L adapter which normally comes with the Canon ES-62 hood designed for the EF 50mm F/1.8 II. The 62-L adapter screws into the 52mm filter threads of any lens that uses 52mm filter threads. Once the 62-L is in place you can use the ES-62 or ET-62 clip on lens hood.

[image]
[image]
[image]

There are third party ES-62 lens hoods available cheaper than Canon, but be careful because many of them are not like the Canon ES-62. Some are actually one piece designs that just screw into the 52mm filter threads. They can not be stored reversed on the lens like a clip on design.

[image]

Others are two piece designs but the hood mounts to the adapter with a bayonet mount instead of a clip on mount. The only problem here is that a Canon ES-62 or ET-62 hood might not mount properly on the third party adapter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The hood you need is the [ET-54](http://shop.usa.canon.com/shop/en/catalog/product-accessories/ef-lens-accessories/lens-hoods/lens-hood-et-54?utm_source=google&utm_medium=Product_Search&utm_campaign=Google_Product_Feed&cm_mmc=GA-_-Lens_Hoods-_-G_Canon_Product%20Listing%20Ads-_-7605). Read the description and it will say that it fits your lens.

There is also a cheaper used one at [adorama](http://www.adorama.com/US%20%20%20%20522064.html)

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, could you please not use URL shorteners to provide links? I'm not sure if there's an SE policy for that, but for me it feels safer if I can see to which link I'm going before I click on it (this was not possible with your x.co link). If a link is very long you can just link a word to the link (like I did now in my edit). Thank you!

Comment: That page says it fits the "80-200 f/4.5-5.6 II", does the original version (not II) use the same mount?

Comment: It looks like the ET-54 uses a bayonet mount on the lens.  The Canon 80-200 f4.5-5.6 I does not have a bayonet mount so I don't think this hood will work.